# How to calculate homography matrix between two cameras, given each camera's instrinsic matrix and the transformation matrix between both cameras?

Tags: computer-vision, homography

How would that be done?

I have two Cameras let it be `A` and `B`. I have the `4x4` transform already between both cameras. I also have the 3x3 intrinsic between both. How do I calculate the 3x3 `homography matrix`?

Comment: what is your 4X4 transform?

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2 different 4x4 projection matrices (and 2 different 3x3 intrinsic matrices), one for each camera.

You should check that one of the camera is the wordl reference frame, and its 4x4 projection matrix P  is equal to P = K[I|0] with I as a 3x3 identity matrix

So you have the intrinsics K and K', and the two 4x4 in this form
P = K[I|0] and P' = K'[R|t] . R and t are the extrinsics, R as a 3x3 rotation matrix and t as a 3x1 translation vector.

**Theory says** that the relation between m points and m' points is
m' = L x K' x R x inv(K) x m + K' x t
with inv(K) is the inverse matrix of K (x is not a variable, just the product symbol). L is a scale factor

This is not a proper homograpy, it could become an homography if t = 0.